# Date List To Date Range List?

Tags: c#, list, date, range

```
Date List        Expected Date Range List
----------       -----------------------
01.11.2018 -->   01.11.2018-01.11.2018
09.11.2018 -
10.11.2018 -->   09.11.2018-10.11.2018
12.11.2018 -
13.11.2018 -
14.11.2018 -->   12.11.2018-14.11.2018
16.11.2018 -->   16.11.2018-16.11.2018
20.11.2018 -
21.11.2018 -->   20.11.2018-21.11.2018
29.11.2018 -->   29.11.2018-29.11.2018
```

How can I get Expected Date Range List from Date List with C#.

Comment: What have you tried, what didn't work, where is this date-list stored(in DB?), what type is this Date-List(because it seems to contain two sometimes), what type is the expected Date-Range-List?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, can you elaborate?

Comment: I am getting Date List from DateTimePicker's selected dates array. So I want to get Date Range List to save to DB. Because of reducing record count to DB. I hope this explanation is enough for you.

Comment: Post the code that isn't working.  Very unclear to us what help you are looking for.  Is this a database question?  A class-structure question?  A List question?

Comment: List question... Algorithm question

Comment: should be easy with some IEnumerable, ifs and yield...

Comment: Even beginner should be able to something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dmspM5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this :

```
var format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var list = new List<DateTime> {
    DateTime.ParseExact("01.11.2018", format, provider),
    DateTime.ParseExact("09.11.2018", format, provider),
    DateTime.ParseExact("10.11.2018", format, provider),
    DateTime.ParseExact("12.11.2018", format, provider),
    DateTime.ParseExact("13.11.2018", format, provider),
    DateTime.ParseExact("14.11.2018", format, provider),
    DateTime.ParseExact("16.11.2018", format, provider),
    DateTime.ParseExact("20.11.2018", format, provider),
    DateTime.ParseExact("21.11.2018", format, provider),
    DateTime.ParseExact("29.11.2018", format, provider),            
};
list.Sort();
var n = list.Count;
var rangelist = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>(n);
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var min = list[i];
    var max = list[i];
    for (var j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        if ((list[j] - max).TotalDays == 1)
            max = list[i = j];
        else
            break;
    rangelist.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(min, max));
}
foreach (var range in rangelist)
    Console.WriteLine(
        range.Item1.ToString(format, provider) + "-" +
        range.Item2.ToString(format, provider));
```

Output:

> 01.11.2018-01.11.2018
>
> 09.11.2018-10.11.2018
>
> 12.11.2018-14.11.2018
>
> 16.11.2018-16.11.2018
>
> 20.11.2018-21.11.2018
>
> 29.11.2018-29.11.2018

Comment: Thank u very much alex.